# Why Gmaps4rails' marker.picture not showing the customized image of the marker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionviewhelper, gmaps4rails2

**I placed the the custom icon in `assets/images/logo.png`**

and in the controller there is :

```
marker.picture({
    "url" => "logo.png" ,
    "width" => 32 ,
    "height" => 32})
```

I even tried replacing `logo.png` by `\assets\images\logo.png` but it does not work.

I checked the size of the logo and it is the same as above.

**What is happening?**

**Update #1** : I tried using `image_path` & `asset_path` and non of them has done the work.

Comment: what did `image_path` return? if its a valid path, it must work

Comment: It returns this , `undefined method 'image_path' for #<DisplayerController:0x42ce7f0> `
Note that `Displayer` controller does not have a model. Only views and no displayer objects.

Comment: what if you do `view_context.image_path` ?

Comment: **Exactly, Thanks!**  
Can you provide me with a little source of wiki to understand what happened ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `view_context.image_path`

The bug is not related to gmaps4rails, which only expects a valid path or url.

It's linked to Rails which doesnt let controller access some view helpers, so you have to use the `view_context` to get them.